# Is the Schofield semi invariant defined at $V/IV$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, invariant-theory, quivers

Let $A=\mathbb{K}Q$ be the path algebra of an acyclic quiver $Q$ over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$, and $0\not=I\subset\mathbb{K}Q$ be an admissible ideal. Let $W$ be a left $A$-module and
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> R_1@>f>>R_0@>>>W@>>>0
\end{CD} be the minimal projective resolution of $W$.
Let $V$ be a left $A$-modules such that the Schofield semi-invariant $c^W(V):=\mathrm{det}(\mathrm{Hom}_{A}(f,V))$ is defined, i.e., $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(R_0,V)=\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(R_1,V)$

> Is it true that $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(R_0,V/IV)=\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(R_1,V/IV)$, i.e., $c^W(V/IV)$ is also defined?